# How do I handle a new certificate with OKHTTP?

Tags: android, http, ssl, okhttp

I'm connecting to an API using OKHTTP. Everything was working just find until today since the API changed their SSL certificate.

Now one of my test devices works fine but the other is failing and logging the following errors:

```
NativeCrypto: ssl=0x605af938 cert_verify_callback x509_store_ctx=0x6055f8b8 arg=0x0
NativeCrypto: ssl=0x605af938 cert_verify_callback calling verifyCertificateChain authMethod=ECDHE_RSA
```

I'm new to HTTP so I'm not sure how to even start resolving this. Any ideas please?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will help someone, due to my testing of another function, the date of my tablet was set to a week ago, so the certificate wasn't valid then.

Stupid error.